# Understanding how firebase handles signing In with JWT

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing JWT authentication using firebase in ExpressJS application where the JWT is generated by firebase itself

in **login.html**

```html
<form method="POST" class="register-form" id="login-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me" class="agree-term" />
                            <label for="remember-me" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-button">
                            <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" class="form-submit" value="Log in"/>
                        </div>

<script>
    // afterinitialzing firebase app
    document
          .getElementById("login-form")
          .addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const login = event.target.email.value;
            const password = event.target.password.value;

            const getToken = () => {
              console.log(login, password);
              return fetch(
                '/getToken', 
                { 
                  method: 'POST', 
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }, 
                  body: JSON.stringify({ 
                          email: login,
                          password: password 
                        }) 
                  }
              )
            }
            getToken();
</script>
```

according to [firebase generate custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) I have to makae a route where I verify user's password and email and get the `uid` and generate token as

```js
app.post('/getToken', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email
  const password = req.body.password

  admin
  .auth()
  .getUserByEmail(email)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    const uid = userRecord.uid;
    admin
    .auth()
    .createCustomToken(uid)
    .then((customToken) => {
      res.json({ token: customToken });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });

})
```

and then complete signing in this way

```js
const getToken = () => {
              console.log(login, password);
              return fetch(
                '/getToken', 
                { 
                  method: 'POST', 
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }, 
                  body: JSON.stringify({ 
                          email: login,
                          password: password 
                        }) 
                  }
              ).then((responseData) => {
                firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                  // Signed in
                  var user = userCredential.user;
                  // ...
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  var errorCode = error.code;
                  var errorMessage = error.message;
                  // ...
                });

              })
            }
            getToken();
```

I hope this is what needs to be done.
I realised in this entire process I am not verifying the password that the user entered anywhere. I have very little knowledge of how jwt works but I want to understand how to verify the user's password as stated in the documentation linked above

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication only or your own database to store user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're minting a custom token for a user in your server-side code, it is **your** responsibility to check whether the credentials for the user are valid. Minting custom tokens is typically done when you have an existing directory of user credentials that you want to integrate with Firebase.

While it *is* possible to check the credentials enter against the data stored in Firebase Authentication fo that user, it is quite involved and it makes little sense to store the credentials in Firebase Authentication when you're minting custom tokens. I have a feeling we're dealing with a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Why don't you [use the Firebase Authentication client-side JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web)? That's going to be much easier, and idiomatic for this scenario.

Comment: as far as I understood I have to verify the user credentials in my case i.e. email and password in the backend and then generate a jwt and assign. If that is the case then I cannot find a way to authenticate the user's password using firebase admin SDK. I can get the email authenticated but not password.

Comment: also I am not using client side js SDK as it is a requirement to handle authentication and database through the backend in the project

Comment: It makes little sense to use Firebase's built-in email+password provider in that scenario. You *can* technically export the password hashes out of Firebase, use the same algorithm and salt to hash the value from the user, and compare those. But at that point, why don't you store the credentials in your own location?